# Xamarin - The "ManifestMerger" task failed unexpectedly

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-manifest

After update visual studio version my Xamarin Forms projects not build, showing me the error below. I tried to create a blank app but same error occurs.

**Error:**

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       The "ManifestMerger" task failed unexpectedly.
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file 'D:\GIT\AppBlank\AppBlank\AppBlank.Android\obj\Debug\110\android\AndroidManifest.xml.tmp'.
File name: 'D:\GIT\AppBlank\AppBlank\AppBlank.Android\obj\Debug\110\android\AndroidManifest.xml.tmp'
   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize)
   at System.Xml.XmlDownloadManager.GetStream(Uri uri, ICredentials credentials, IWebProxy proxy, RequestCachePolicy cachePolicy)
   at System.Xml.XmlUrlResolver.GetEntity(Uri absoluteUri, String role, Type ofObjectToReturn)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.FinishInitUriString()
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl..ctor(String uriStr, XmlReaderSettings settings, XmlParserContext context, XmlResolver uriResolver)
   at System.Xml.XmlReaderSettings.CreateReader(String inputUri, XmlParserContext inputContext)
   at System.Xml.XmlReader.Create(String inputUri, XmlReaderSettings settings, XmlParserContext inputContext)
   at System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Load(String uri, LoadOptions options)
   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ManifestDocument..ctor(String templateFilename)
   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ManifestMerger.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.<ExecuteInstantiatedTask>d__26.MoveNext() AppBlank.Android
```

**Output build:**

```
Rebuild started...
Restored D:\GIT\AppBlank\AppBlank\AppBlank\AppBlank.csproj (in 29 ms).
1>------ Rebuild All started: Project: AppBlank, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
Restored D:\GIT\AppBlank\AppBlank\AppBlank.Android\AppBlank.Android.csproj (in 99 ms).
1>AppBlank -> D:\GIT\AppBlank\AppBlank\AppBlank\bin\Debug\netstandard2.0\AppBlank.dll
2>------ Rebuild All started: Project: AppBlank.Android, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
2>  AppBlank.Android -> D:\GIT\AppBlank\AppBlank\AppBlank.Android\bin\Debug\AppBlank.Android.dll
2>D:\Arquivos de Programas\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1448,3): error MSB4018: The "ManifestMerger" task failed unexpectedly.
2>D:\Arquivos de Programas\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1448,3): error MSB4018: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file 'D:\GIT\AppBlank\AppBlank\AppBlank.Android\obj\Debug\110\android\AndroidManifest.xml.tmp'.
2>D:\Arquivos de Programas\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1448,3): error MSB4018: File name: 'D:\GIT\AppBlank\AppBlank\AppBlank.Android\obj\Debug\110\android\AndroidManifest.xml.tmp'
2>D:\Arquivos de Programas\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1448,3): error MSB4018:    at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
2>D:\Arquivos de Programas\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1448,3): error MSB4018:    at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
2>D:\Arquivos de Programas\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1448,3): error MSB4018:    at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize)
2>D:\Arquivos de Programas\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1448,3): error MSB4018:    at System.Xml.XmlDownloadManager.GetStream(Uri uri, ICredentials credentials, IWebProxy proxy, RequestCachePolicy cachePolicy)
2>D:\Arquivos de Programas\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1448,3): error MSB4018:    at System.Xml.XmlUrlResolver.GetEntity(Uri absoluteUri, String role, Type ofObjectToReturn)
2>D:\Arquivos de Programas\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1448,3): error MSB4018:    at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.FinishInitUriString()
2>D:\Arquivos de Programas\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1448,3): error MSB4018:    at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl..ctor(String uriStr, XmlReaderSettings settings, XmlParserContext context, XmlResolver uriResolver)
2>D:\Arquivos de Programas\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1448,3): error MSB4018:    at System.Xml.XmlReaderSettings.CreateReader(String inputUri, XmlParserContext inputContext)
2>D:\Arquivos de Programas\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1448,3): error MSB4018:    at System.Xml.XmlReader.Create(String inputUri, XmlReaderSettings settings, XmlParserContext inputContext)
2>D:\Arquivos de Programas\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1448,3): error MSB4018:    at System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Load(String uri, LoadOptions options)
2>D:\Arquivos de Programas\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1448,3): error MSB4018:    at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ManifestDocument..ctor(String templateFilename)
2>D:\Arquivos de Programas\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1448,3): error MSB4018:    at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ManifestMerger.Execute()
2>D:\Arquivos de Programas\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1448,3): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
2>D:\Arquivos de Programas\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1448,3): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.<ExecuteInstantiatedTask>d__26.MoveNext()
========== Rebuild All: 1 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

To try correct, I tried downgrade version Xamarin.Forms to 4.6.0.847 version and add tools in AndroidManifest.xml, but not work.

**Enviroment:**

Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019 Version 16.10.3 for Windows

Xamarin.Android SDK   11.3.0.4

Xamarin.Forms 5.0.0.2083

Target framework: Android 11.0 (R)

**Reproduction:**
https://github.com/FlavineiOliveira/AppBlank

Comment: Your link cannot be opened, and I could not reproduce the issue with the same enviroment as you. You could check your link and update it.

Answer (score 1):

Now the problem was solved, but I dont idea as it happened.

Before, I tried:

1. Clean and rebuild solution
2. Delete folders bin, obj and rebuild solution
3. Update and downgrade Xamarin.Forms version
4. Close and open solution to rebuild
5. Restart my computer
6. Repair Visual Studio
7. Uninstall and install Visual Studio

**Now, I just open the solution and try rebuild.**

**Success.**

The environment is same.